# JQuery Bootstrap closed.bs.alert

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Não estou conseguindo executar o código do evento "closed.bs.alert".

Ou seja, executar um código após a total remoção de um trecho de código disparado quando se clica no botão Close do Alert no Bootstrap.

HTML:

```
<button id="btn_add">
  Add
</button>
<div id="result">
  <div class="col-md-12 alert">
      <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
      <div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-heading">0 [fixed]</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count = 1;
    $("#btn_add").click(function(){
        var str =   '<div class="col-md-12 alert">'+
                        '<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>'+
                        '<div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-heading">'+count+' [dynamic]</div>'+
                    '</div>';
        $("#result").html($("#result").html()+str);
        count++;
    });
    $(".alert").on('closed.bs.alert', function(){
        alert('The alert message is now closed.');
    });
});
```

Código disponível [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/danilotostes/csdzaLmb/3/), no jsfiddle.

No caso, o Bootstrap Alert fixo funciona, mas o dinâmico não. Ou seja, **nos alertas criados dinamicamente eu não consigo executar o código do evento "closed.bs.alert"**.

Deve ser algo simples que não tô conseguindo resolver, talvez deveria implementar algo com This ou criar Ids únicos para cada alerta dinâmico que se cria.

Obs: após criar um alerta dinâmico o alerta fixo também deixar de funcionar para o evento "closed.bs.alert".

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/danilotostes/csdzaLmb/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mude para algo do tipo:

```
$(document).on('click', '.alert a.close', function() {
  alert("OK");
})
```

Veja funcionando no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/csdzaLmb/4/)

Comment: Funcionou aqui.

O fundamental foi usar "document" para resultado idêntico ao "closed.bs.alert".

Pois minha necessidade era justamente que executasse o código após a exclusão do elemento e não antes.

Para minha surpresa funcionou assim perfeitamente.

Existem "closed.bs.alert" e "close.bs.alert". Uma funciona antes e a outra depois do evento disparado. Mas no meu caso não estava rolando.

Comment: @DaniloTostes que bom, se a minha solução resolveu o seu problema, não se esqueça de marca-la como aceita.

Comment: It's done, man!